# Xpath content not saved

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, scraper

It might just be an idiotic bug in the code that I haven't yet discovered, but it's been taking me quite some time: When parsing websites using nokogiri and xpath, and trying to save the content of the xpaths to a .csv file, the csv file has empty cells.

Basically, the content of the xpath returns empty OR my code doesn't properly read the websites.

This is what I'm doing:

```
require 'open-uri'
 require 'nokogiri'
 require 'csv'

CSV.open("neverend.csv", "w") do |csv|
csv << ["kuk","date","name"]

#first, open the urls from a document. The urls are correct.
File.foreach("neverendurls.txt") do |line|    

#second, the loop for each url
searchablefile = Nokogiri::HTML(open(line))

#third, the xpaths. These work when I try them on the website.
kuk = searchablefile.at_xpath("(//tbody/tr/td[contains(@style,'60px')])[1]")
date = searchablefile.at_xpath("(//tbody/tr/td[contains(@style,'60px')])[1]/following-sibling::*[1]")
name = searchablefile.at_xpath("(//tbody/tr/td[contains(@style, '60px')])[1]/following-sibling::*[2]")

#fourth, saving the xpaths
csv <<  [kuk,date,name]

end 
end
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: I think i have the answer.. (1) Don't trust in-browser xpath checking. (2) watch out for <tbody>, don't use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to tell from what you posted, but let's clean that hot mess up with css:

```
kuk  = searchablefile.at 'td[style*=60px]'
date = searchablefile.at 'td[style*=60px] + *'
name = searchablefile.at 'td[style*=60px] + * + *'
```